# Module exports. Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and i have some questons. I'm implementing simple chat app and in ordor to do that I'm using ExpressJS + Nodejs + Sockert.io bundle. 
Here is my UserServive.js

```
var db = require('../db')

class UserService {

    findUserByNick(nick, callback) {
        let userCollection = db.get('usercollection')
        userCollection.findOne({username: nick}, (error, data) => {
            callback(error, data);
        });
    }

    findUserByEmail(email, callback) {
        let userCollection = db.get('usercollection')
        userCollection.findOne({email: nick}, (error, data) => {
            callback(error, data);
        });
    }
}

var us = new UserService();
module.exports = us;
```

Is it acceptable export object instance? Or I should make all methids static like in this code:

```
class tokens_controller extends require('./controller_utils') {
    static check_token(token_data, callback) {
        if (this.validator(token_data, valid_templates.tokens.check_token, callback)) {
            this.get_token_info(token_data.access_token, (get_token_info_err, get_token_info_result)=> {
                TOKENS_MODEL.update({token: token_data.access_token}, (update_error, update_result)=> {
                    console.log(update_result);
                    if (update_error) {
                        callback(update_error, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        USERS_MODEL.find_users({
                            find: [{user_id: update_result.user_id}],
                            nots: ['password']
                        }, (find_users_error, find_users_result)=> {
                            if (find_users_error) {
                                callback(find_users_error, null);
                            }
                            else {
                                let user = find_users_result[0];
                                let result = {user: user, token: update_result};
                                callback(null, result);
                            }

                        });
                    }
                });
            }, callback);

        }
    }
}
module.exports = tokens_controller;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a service and you don't need to play with `this` or something you can just omit the class behavior and only export an object.

```
var db = require('../db')

module.exports = {

    findUserByNick: function(nick, callback) {
        let userCollection = db.get('usercollection')
        userCollection.findOne({username: nick}, (error, data) => {
            callback(error, data);
        });
    },

    findUserByEmail: function(email, callback) {
        let userCollection = db.get('usercollection')
        userCollection.findOne({email: nick}, (error, data) => {
            callback(error, data);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js developers don't like putting stuff on the global scope. This is for example how I do it:

```
module.exports = function() {
    class MyClass {
        // Stuff
    }

    return MyClass;
}
```

Then in the main file:

```
const MyClass = require("./MyClass.js")();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do in your UserService.

```
export default UserService;
```

And then

```
import UserService from './userService';
new UserService()
```